# PowerShell - PowerCLI expand Array

Tags: powershell, powercli

Here is my script:

```
$1 = get-view -viewtype ClusterComputeResource
$1 | select name,datastore
```

Output:

```
Name                     Datastore
----                     ---------
Cluster1                 {Datastore-datastore-1, Datastore-datastore-2}
Cluster2                 {Datastore-datastore-2, Datastore-datastore-3}
Cluster3                 {Datastore-datastore-3, Datastore-datastore-4}
```

What I need is to have output formated so it looks like this:

```
Name                     Datastore
----                     ---------
Cluster1         Datastore-datastore-1
Cluster1         Datastore-datastore-2
Cluster2         Datastore-datastore-2
Cluster2         Datastore-datastore-3
Cluster3         Datastore-datastore-3
Cluster3         Datastore-datastore-4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: probably this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494201/output-a-hashtable-of-arrays-in-powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, figured out the answer:

```
$1 = get-view -viewtype ClusterComputeResource | select name,datastore
$table1 = @()
    foreach ($datastore in $1.Datastore) {
      $table = " " | select datastore_ID,Cluster_Name
      $table.datastore_ID = $datastore
      $table.Cluster_name =  $1.Name
      $table1 += $table
}
```